# Jekyll How to get add Youtube Channel link to socials in minima template?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, minima

I'm very new to Jekyll (and web development in general) and am trying to use it to make a Portfolio website. I make YouTube Tutorials as well as text ones and want to link them using the built in social to the minima theme.

```
youtube_username: AgentArachnid
youtube_url: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3vRLT5pJCbctTmoESVNYPw
```

I've tried following [these steps](https://blog.jakelee.co.uk/adding-new-social-media-link-to-minima/) and adapt to just use the default youtube setup but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

[image: image|661x500]

As you can in the picture when I hover over the Youtube link, it'll redirect me to youtube.com/AgentArachnid. I want the name to be maintained but the url it will direct me to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

With Jekyll, if you are trying to add the link to a single page generated from a markdown file, you can add `[Text to display for link](URL for link to direct to)` which is the markdown way to code the link.

If you want to add a link to an HTML template such as the HTML file of the landing page, then you can use an anchor tag like `<a href="URL for link to direct to">Text to display</a>` and this will add the link to the template.

With Jekyll Liquid templating, you can also reference values from the front matter but the effect is the same e.g. if you have `title` defined in your `_config.yml` then you can reference it in the template with `{{ site.title }}` and very similar for values defined specific to a page/post.